# What it the Big O time complexity for findIslands ( leet code )?

Tags: javascript, big-o, breadth-first-search

One can see that it has 2 for loops, which would be O(n * m), however, in the inner loop there is a breadth first search.

Because the islands are randomly generated, it seems difficult to quantify how much time this will add.

```
/*

    https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-islands/
*/

const grid = [
  [0, 1, 1, 0],
  [0, 1, 1, 0],
  [1, 0, 0, 0],
  [1, 1, 0, 0],
];

function findIslands() {
  let count = 0;

  // traverse each row
  for(let i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {

    // traverse each column in the row
    for(let j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
      if(grid[i][j]) {
        count++;
        markIsland(i, j);
      }
    }
  }
  return count;
}

function markIsland(i, j) {

  // if either out of bounds or water(0) hit, do not recurse further
  if( i < 0 || j < 0 || i >= grid.length || j >= grid[i].length || grid[i][j] === 0 ) {
    return;
  }

  // mark the entire island as water to avoid recursing it again
  grid[i][j] = 0;

  // recurse in all 4 directions
  markIsland(i-1, j);     //  up
  markIsland(i,   j+1);   //  right
  markIsland(i+1, j);     //  down
  markIsland(i,   j-1);   //  left
}

console.log(findIslands());
```

Answer (score 1):

It is O(N^2). The loop takes O(N^2). Then the breadth first searches count each 1 exactly one time, so in total, they take O(N^2). Thus, the total is O(N^2) + O(N^2) = O(N^2).

For problems like this, you can't use the simple time complexity calculation of just counting the loops, because the body of each loop could potentially be O(N^2), which gives you O(N^4) as a upper bound, which is too loose.

Answer (score 1):

Worst-case (which this sort of complexity test is usually checking, when not otherwise specified), the number of islands is directly proportional to the length and width of the grid. For example, with a 4x4 grid, you could have 8 islands:

```
xoxo
oxox
xoxo
oxox
```

That said, the number of islands isn't really an issue for complexity here, I think, because each top-level call of `markIsland` will either:

- terminate immediately when a 0 is found, or
- recursively call `markIsland` (for a total of no more than `length * width` calls over the entire nested loop)

So the overall complexity can be said to be `O(n ^ 2)`.

Comment: I see what you are saying with worst case, it will mark a 0 and recurse 4 times, each calling the if statement, for a total of four checks per island.  It is 4 per island and not dependent upon x or y dimension of the grid ... the answer is it does not contribute b.c. it is an operation with in the two loops not effected by x or y.  What is n?  There is no n though.  That seems to be an error.  ( grid is not square, it is x by y or n by m have you)

Comment: Should be ... I believe ... O ( n * m )

Comment: (1) Easier to disregard the number of checks per island, and instead consider that the total number of `markIsland` calls won't exceed a small number for each square - 4 adjacent checks during recursion, and one check during the main loop. So, in terms of O notation, it's directly proportional to the number of squares. (2) Oh, sure, yep, so `O(n * m)`.